# How to properly walk a disk directory recursively and stream all the paths in relative format into a json using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read directory tree and save it into a JSON file using node.js with the following logic:

1. Read specified directory
2. Transform (or get in the first place if possible?) the paths into `relative` format. Something like this:

**Directory:**  `C:/test`

```
{
{"C:/test folder 1": [
  {"folder 1": ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]}, 
  "file1.txt",
  "file2.txt",
  ...
]},
{"C:/test folder 2": [
  {"folder 1": ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]}, 
  "file1.txt",
  "file2.txt",
  ...
]},
"file1.txt",
"file2.txt",
"file3.txt",
...
}
```

3. Stream that object into a JSON file (I need to stream it because the object is quite big)

I was trying to use different npm modules like:

`walkdir`, `walker`, `node-klaw` + `fs-extra.writeJson`, `json-object-stream`, etc.

But I keep getting different errors trying to stream it into a json.

Comment: `But I keep getting different errors`, it might help if you tell us what they were,.  eg, Show us the code you used when doing `walk`, and what errors you got.

Comment: @Keith at this point the formatting code I have is quite a mess, I cannot make a proper object with `relative` formatted paths. I'm formatting the paths with this regex: `item.match(/[^\\\/]+$/)[0]` but I cannot make a proper structure out of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following script should work for you, just replace __dirname with absolute path of location that you want to list. And update filename where to write it

I am not checking here if first time call actually gets valid folder, and there might be thing with / regarding on OS

removeNamespace flag here is only so that first level keeps absolute path and not in following

```
var fs = require("fs");

function getContentForLocation(location, removeNamespace) {
    let result = [];
    let content = fs.readdirSync(location);
    content.forEach(c => {
        if(fs.statSync(`${location}/${c}`).isFile()) result.push(c);
        else {
            let name = removeNamespace ? c : `${location}/${c}`;
            result.push({
                [`${name}`]: getContentForLocation(`${location}/${c}`, true)
            })
        }
    });
    return result;
}
let tree = JSON.stringify(getContentForLocation(__dirname))
fs.writeFileSync(`${__dirname}/test.json`, tree)
```

Async version:

```
var fs = require("fs");

function getContentForLocation(location, callback, removeNamespace) {
    let result = [];

    let folderNames = [];
    fs.readdir(location, (err, content) => {
        content.forEach(c => {
            if(fs.statSync(`${location}/${c}`).isFile()) result.push(c);
            else folderNames.push(c);
        });
        if(folderNames.length === 0) callback(result)
        else folderNames.forEach(folder => {
            let name = removeNamespace ? folder : `${location}/${folder}`;
            getContentForLocation(`${location}/${folder}`, resolveCallback.bind(this, name, folder),true)
        })
    });

    function resolveCallback(name, folder, content) {
        result.push({ [name]: content });
        folderNames = folderNames.filter(f => f !== folder);
        if(folderNames.length === 0) callback(result);
    }
}

getContentForLocation(__dirname, results => {
    console.log("resolved", results)
    fs.writeFile(`${__dirname}/test.json`, JSON.stringify(results), (err) => { console.log(err) })
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Node handles slashes properly, so that shouldn't be a problem. And that `removeNamespace` flag is a nice touch as well, thanks

Comment: Tnx, in output there might only bit issue with slashes for what you want (escaping etc).
Possible future improvement, depending on needs, could be instead of using Sync functions using non blocking ones.

Comment: Yeah, for sure, I'll try to convert it to read/write streams and pipe it through to make it async. There shouldn't be any problems right? Just create a `createReadStream` and pipe `readdir` into it and then pipe `JSON.stringify` into that, right?

Comment: Dont think there is need for stream, just using readdir should be enough. Don't get lost with callbacks 
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback. For writting it is fs.writeFile

Comment: It should be enough for smaller dirs, although I got a 200mb JSON file back, so yeah...  I should probably use streams to not run out of RAM

Comment: @Un1 JSON is not really something you can stream, but the 200mb object in node should not be an issue.  But one thing I will point out, this is `sync`,  so do be aware of the pitfalls of doing it this way,. eg. If you had this running in an express website, your going to block all requests until this is complete.

Comment: @Keith The problem with 200mb is that it results in 1GB+ of RAM usage because of the overhead during writing. Regarding the async, sure that's why I mentioned I need it to be written with a stream, thanks for the advice though

Comment: @Un1 `why I mentioned I need it to be written with a stream`  Writing something to a stream has nothing to do with something been `async` / `sync`.  If you updated the above code to do streams, it's still going to block the node process.  Basically, all those `sync` methods need removing to stop this from happening.

Comment: @chriss  `readdir` is but your using `readdirSync`, so it's going to block node's event pump until this function is complete.

Comment: Yeah it is what i said in second comment but didnt have time to write that one also. I edited answer to contain both sync and async. Async is a bit more complex as it needs multiple callbacks handling

Comment: @chriss sorry, I'm getting lost in the recursion, If I may ask one more question please - is there an easy way to change that `sync` function so that it simply pushes all the paths into `result = []` without creating the nested structure? E.g. return simple array: `["image1.jpg", "folder 1", "file 1.txt"]` instead of `["image1.jpg", {"folder 1": [file 1.txt]}]` ? I'm trying to modify it to do that (to measure performance impact) but I'm loosing nested folders and files

Comment: Sadly cant do it here at the moment, but if you want that you can reuse existing npm package location-tree, https://github.com/kristijan-pajtasev/location-tree